# Scaffolding Identity without registration page in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, scaffolding

Good day,

I am developing an ASP.NET Core Blazor App in .NET Core 3.0. I have already implemented many features. Now I want to add login/logout functionality. I want to scaffold **Identity** to my application.

Now *Identity* comes with multiple features but I only want **Login** and **Logout** functionality. I do not want registration or social logins.

I want to know both ways to achieve it. i.e. Through "Add new Scaffold item> Identity" then Add migration and update migration. Also, through scaffold command in the package manager console.

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but can't you simply delete the pages you don't want to customize after scaffolding everything? Chance is that the build in pages are used when scaffolded pages don't exist.

Comment: Scaffolding is only required when you want to change the look&feel. All pages are packed into the package. Just ignore what you don't need.

Comment: If you do not want registration and external login, you just remove related html on `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` and `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml` after you scaffolding (choose Login/Logout)